# What does the "no command" screen mean? (Trying to execute hard reset Recovery)

Tags: moto-x, hard-reset

I'm trying to hard reset a Motorola XT1058 I inherited from my sister that's sending me to the No command screen.

When I press the all of the <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>VolUp</kbd> + <kbd>VolDown</kbd> for a while and release which takes me to the `AP Fastboot Flash Mode` screen, which reads as follows :

```
AP Fastboot Flash Mode (S)
30.BE (sha-34b7ccb, 2015-04-22 12:57:17)
eMMC: 16GB Sandisk RV=06 PV=07 TY=17
DRAM: 2048MB Hynix S4 SDRAM DIE=4GB
Up Time: 3 minutes
Device is LOCKED. Status Code: 0
Battery OK
Connect USB Data Cable

Boot Mode Selection Menu
Vol Up Selects, Vol Down Scrolls
Normal Powerup
Recovery
Factory
Barcodes
BP Tools
------------------
Fastbook Reason: Key pressed
```

I then navigate to Recovery and that takes me to the `No Command` page. What exactly is this `No Command` page about? I wonder if it's related to the `Device is LOCKED` message that shows up in the Flash Mode screen? My sister does have a password enabled on the device. Maybe she has to first disable it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moto X [Factory Reset](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/94936/related/1) is possible in two ways:

- Settings → Backup & reset →Factory Data Reset →Reset Phone.

**OR**

Alternate way (External Reset below)

- <kbd>Vol Dn</kbd>  + <kbd>Power</kbd>  press for few seconds
- From the "Boot Mode Selection Menu" screen, select Recovery.

Note: Use the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> button to scroll through the menu options and the <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> button to select.

- From the **"No Command"** screen (Android figure lying on his back), press and hold the <kbd>Power</kbd> then press and release the <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> button to display the menu options.
- Select "wipe data/factory reset".

Note: Use the <kbd>Volume</kbd> buttons to highlight and the <kbd>Power</kbd> button to select.

- Select Yes - delete all user data

As you can see from above, you are at the intermediate step of factory reset, while the first method is far simpler

`Device is LOCKED` refers to the status corresponding to Bootloader is locked. It has nothing to do with security password

Huge thanks to [acejavelin](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155705/what-does-the-no-command-screen-mean-trying-to-execute-hard-reset-recovery/155706?noredirect=1#comment199593_155706) for providing an explanation of *No Command*, reproduced:

> The No Command screen means recovery checked the normal area (/cache) for an update file, like an OTA, and it didn't find one, so it had "No Command" to execute. Android's stock recovery is intended for the normal, everyday user, giving them a menu they could easily access could cause lots of potentially angry people who are just playing around and reset their device by accident. Stock recovery, and it's menu, are specifically engineered so that you have to take special steps to do anything. The No Command screen, meaning no automated script, is part of that safe guard.

Comment: Solid, that relates to the Device is LOCKED part and managing to get me to succeed with the Hard Reset. But what exactly is the purpose or design of the No Command page in the first place? What is it meant to communicate precisely?

Comment: The No Command screen means recovery checked the normal area (/cache) for an update file, like an OTA, and it didn't find one, so it had "No Command" to execute. Android's stock recovery is intended for the normal, everyday user, giving them a menu they could easily access could cause lots of potentially angry people who are just playing around and reset their device by accident. Stock recovery, and it's menu, are specifically engineered so that you have to take special steps to do anything. The No Command screen, meaning no automated script, is part of that safe guard.

Comment: @beeshyams Sorry, for what it is worth on this one I am the source... the answer comes from experience and personal observation since the days of Eclair when I started with Android, you can quote it if you wish.

Comment: Thanks you so much. All the instructions on line were wrong, and were saying hold VOLUP and then press PWR, when it was actually hold PWR and press VOLUP.

Comment: @DragonFax glad it helped