# is it possible to delete a file from system folder without being root?

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, fastboot, bootloader, clockworkmod-recovery

I found this file: /system/recovery-from-boot.p and I've read this is preventing me from entering in the recovery mode, but as I'm not root, I can't find a way to delete it or rename it...any suggestion, please?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/222361/recovery-mode-doesnt-work/222363?noredirect=1#comment288499_222361

Comment: Yes, it is possible to delete files without root. for example one could convert and mount system.img, delete files, re-convert into sparse image and flash modified system image (from fastboot or flash tool). But this special file you mention is renamed automatically from twrp (if you swipe to modify system on twrp initial splash screen)

Comment: @alecxs I flashed with twrp and it didn't change. I think the problem may be that twrp is not working on my phone