# how to bypass screen lock password on Ira Comet (2012 model)?

Tags: recovery-mode, lock-screens, password, sim-unlocking

How do I bypass screen-lock password on Ira Comet (2012 model)? From Wishtel. No specific tutorials on this model online. 
In trying to hard reset:--
I cannot get into recovery mode, I mean, not all the way. It stops at the  stage of the fallen down Android with the exclamation mark. No text lines appear to choose further reset settings, no matter what button-combinations I use (power+volume-up, etc etc)! After a while of just waiting the tab goes off entirely. I can of course restart it to the normal screen with image n lock-screen prompt.
The tablet is wifi, but the screen was locked when the internet as off so cannot access the net. I am not even getting any prompt to reset the password no matter how many wrong passwords I type in one after the other. It does not seem to have any reset pinhole either. It has no usb debugging done either.
Can anyone suggest a way to unlock the password, or how to go to full recovery mode on it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "no command" screen mean? (Trying to execute hard reset Recovery)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155705/what-does-the-no-command-screen-mean-trying-to-execute-hard-reset-recovery)

Comment: if still running Android ICS 4.0 "Ice Cream Sandwich" there is no OEM lock or FRP,  you can just `fastboot flashing unlock` in bootloader mode

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. But the Ira Comet (of 2012, from Wishtel) was updated to Marshmallow, I was told, so maybe that FRP is now in place and preventing any further hard reset beyond that fallen-down Android with the exclamation mark - So maybe it's in coma forever... I cannot access anything even through USB cables as there's been no debugging done on it so it does not even charge through the usb cable.

Comment: usb-debugging is not required for fastboot, try Volume-Down + Power to enter bootloader mode

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/127739