# Vodafone VFD 100 android 5.0 phone shows "no command" on recovery mode

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, recovery-mode

I have a problem with my android 5.0 Vodafone VFD 100 phone.
So it restarted on its own, and then showed the message “Android is starting, optimizing app x of y” (not the first time). There were 19 apps in total and it got stuck on app number 11. I got impatient and since restarting it brought me to the same place, I removed the battery while it was optimizing apps. Now it won’t boot thereafter. I have tried several suggestions to no avail. When I switch to recovery mode, it displays “no command” on a blank screen after “input language=> English” after choosing the language. Please help as soon as possible since I’m currently stuck.
Regards.

Comment: Have you performed a factory reset?

Comment: @Robert It doesn't show any other options after the "select language=> English" apart from "no command"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "no command" screen mean? (Trying to execute hard reset Recovery)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155705/what-does-the-no-command-screen-mean-trying-to-execute-hard-reset-recovery)

Comment: the "optimizing" process is to generate dalvik-cache and must not disturbed

Answer (score 1):

You should flash a custom recovery, then reboot your phone in recovery. And then in the recovery, wipe the Dalvik-cache.

Comment: How should one flash something when android does not boot and there is no way to OEM unlock in developer options? (btw OP don't know how to enter recovery mode at all)

Comment: Android does boot but there is no recovery installed. This is why it says no command. To access the bootloader on most android phones, you have to hold Power and Volume - and + until the bootloader screen appears.

Comment: Android does **not** boot thats why OP want to factory reset in first place. have you read what the *No command* screen means, and how you can enter recovery from *No command* screen?

Comment: [https://www.androiddata-recovery.com/blog/solved-no-command-error-in-recovery-mode-on-android](https://www.androiddata-recovery.com/blog/solved-no-command-error-in-recovery-mode-on-android)