# i cant go to recovery mode NO Command error, Boot-loop

Tags: samsung, boot-loop, unbricking

I recently tried to install a custom ROM in my samsung j6+ but halfway through it my PC turned off(disconnected while flashing).
Then the problem starts i decided to reboot my phone but it shows this message
"No command" " #Reboot recovery cause is [[check_bootmode]RebootRecoveryWithKey]#
Block-based OTA
Supported API: 3

## MANUAL MODE v1.0.0#

E:Failed to mount / cache: Invalid argument

The error message keeps appearing for just a fraction of a second then disappear and appear again

I tried to go to recovery mode but no luck i cant get to it
I drained the battery to turn off the device then go download mode but after get to it, it also keep restarting

Please help me thanks so much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "no command" screen mean? (Trying to execute hard reset Recovery)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155705/what-does-the-no-command-screen-mean-trying-to-execute-hard-reset-recovery)