# Unlock Xiaomi without USB debugging

Tags: adb, sim-unlocking

I'm currently having problems unlocking my Xiaomi Mi A2 Lite. I've tried hard resetting it through the old volume down (or up) + power but it always ends up showing "No command", no matter how many times I try it.
I've also tried entering recovery mode through ADB, but being that USB debbuging is disabled, it won't even detect the device.
I don't have a Google account linked to the phone, so I don't know what else to do.
All support is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "no command" screen mean? (Trying to execute hard reset Recovery)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155705/what-does-the-no-command-screen-mean-trying-to-execute-hard-reset-recovery)

Comment: Nope, thing is, I can't reach the Boot Mode Selection Menu, vol up + power will lead me to the "No command" screen, and vol down + power to fastboot (don't know if I can do something from here but I don't think so)

Comment: Ohhh it's true, I didn't correctly read it the first time, thank you so much!