# How to reinstall (or install) android 6 (7) on HTC one m9 plus?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, installation, htc, htc-one

My HTC one m9 plus OS is not working properly (e.g. It reboots several times when I turn on WIFI or data, etc) So I decided to install Android 6 or 7 on it. But after downloading [this file](https://archive.org/details/htc_m9_plus_firmware)

During the installation (using adb or putting OS file directly into smartphone's SD card and pressing Power+ - keys in locked mode) it return an error.

Probably these errors occur because of unofficial version of OS. If so where can I download official Android 6 or 7 for HTC one m9 plus? and how do I install it?

**UPDATE:** Recovery try:

1. press and hold the Power button together with the Volume Down key and hold them until you can see the Download Mode on your screen.
2. select the reboot to bootloader option.

[image]

3. go to the boot to Recovery Mode option.

after choosing Recovery Mode it shows the following:

[image]

My smartphone details is as follow:

```
S-ON
htc_hiau_ml_thul PVT
LK-1.01.0000
RADIO -UNKNOWN
openDSP-UNKNOWN
OS-2.30.401.1
```

I've tried the following with `cid_num error`:

```
modelid: 0PK711000
cidnum: HTC__001
cidnum: HTC__J15
cidnum: HTC__M27
cidnum: HTC__032
cidnum: HTC__Y13
cidnum: HTC__031
cidnum: HTC__102
cidnum: HTC__A07
mainver: 1.85.401.6

modelid: 0PK711000
cidnum: HTC__044
cidnum: HTC__038
mainver: 2.30.707.1
```

and this unrelated one:

```
modelid: 0PJA10000
cidnum: HTC__001
cidnum: HTC__J15
cidnum: HTC__102
cidnum: HTC__M27
cidnum: HTC__002
cidnum: HTC__032
cidnum: HTC__016
cidnum: HTC__031
cidnum: HTC__A07
cidnum: HTC__Y13
mainver: 4.28.401.3
```

Comment: please note android ROM is read-only, it's very unlikely that installing ROM will fix anything. best fix is factory reset. the file you tried to install is update.zip. you can find proper update from > Settings > About > Software updates https://www.htc.com/mea-en/support/htc-one-m9-plus/howto/631756.html

Comment: The keyword for finding official Android firmware binaries (often with installer) from HTC is "RUU", search for your model with RUU and I am sure you will find some installers.

Comment: @alecxs: It is impossible to update or do anything with Android setting itself such as About > Software updates, because it don't allow me to turn on WIFI or data and it reboots quickly.

Comment: @alecxs: I've tried it as well, but after some minutes nothing changed. All my previous apps were there.

Comment: @alecxs: So what is its remedy?

Comment: https://www.hardreset.info/devices/htc/htc-one-m9-plus kindly repeat this and post the error/success message here (edit question)

Comment: @alecxs: after step 4, it shows smartphone image and a red danger sign inside a red triangle. and reboots after a while.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "no command" screen mean? (Trying to execute hard reset Recovery)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/155705/what-does-the-no-command-screen-mean-trying-to-execute-hard-reset-recovery)

Comment: @alecxs: it is related but my "No Command" screen is not Android figure lying on his back!

Comment: please go on with Roberts suggestion. I have other things in mind (if everything else failed) there are quite few expert tools for mediatek

Comment: *'fastboot oem rebootRUU;
htc_fastboot flash zip ruu.zip'*