# How could I find a recovery image for an obscure phone?

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot

I have a phone (Alba 6), and it will not boot into the OS. I tried to go into recovery mode by holding the power and volume up buttons. This would have worked, but in place of the recovery menu coming up, a screen came up that said "No command". Apparently, to fix this, I need to flash a recovery image to my phone using fastboot (because I don't have USB debugging enabled and I obviously can't enable it currently). The problem is, I do not have a recovery image to use, nor can I find one. I came across TWRP, but my phone is very obscure, and there is no image available for it. Do any of you have an image, or know where I could find one? Is there a standardised image I could use? What are the steps I could take to get this phone fixed?

Comment: the [no command](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/155705) screen is part of stock recovery.

Comment: @alecxs Oh. In that case, how do I navigate to the actual recovery menu so that I can back up and reset?

Comment: regarding unlocking bootloader and TWRP maybe ask in that [thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/is-my-life-really-worth-it.4217751/post-84295797)

Comment: for backup you need SPD Research Tool (and some files)